# How to detect when 1 of 2 elements is visible using Selenium?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I need some help trying to figure out how to tell when one of two elements is visible with Selenium.

Basically, there's a search field and a list of results. If the text isn't found then `No Results Found` is displayed. I'm trying to detect when either the list isn't there and no results are found, or the other way around(when the list is visible). The point is to add the text that's not found to the list, or if it's found then click it.

Here's the basic HTML I'm working with. It's written in React and the table updates to take the place of the `<div>` wrapping the `<p>`.

```
<div class="related-files-adder">
    <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth">
        <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl">
            <input placeholder="Search..." type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"> <!-- this is the input field -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="this is where the both no results and the table lives">
        <div> <!-- this divider changes to the table -->
            <p class="lead">No Results Found</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to detect if either was visible using: `EC.any_of(EC.visibility_of_element_located(element1), EC.visibility_of_element_located(element2))`, but in testing both conditions independently, I found it was returning true regardless of the state.

```
if (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, restultsTablePath))):
    print("this is true when 'no restults' are displayed.")
if (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, noResultsPath))):
    print("this is true when the table is being dispalyed.")
```

This seems to be promising, but throws a `NoSuchElement` Exception if the table or `No Results` message isn't visible.

```
if (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, restultsTablePath).is_displayed()):
    print("this returns true when the table is visible, but crashes when it's not")
```

Is this an issue caused by `staleness` when the window updates to display the list? I was trying to use `driverWait.until(EC.staleness_of())` but couldn't figure out what I should be checking the staleness of? The `<div>` wrapping the entire thing?

How can I check for an element that's not visible without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement method that checks if element exists and displayed.
To achieve this you should call `find_elements` - this method doesn't throw an exception if element is not exist.

Then you should filter array to get all elements where `is_displayed` returns `True`. If collection length > 0, so your element exists and displayed.

If there is no such element or element is not displayed, collection length would be 0, so method would return `False`.

```py
def element_exist_and_displayed(by, locator):
    elements = driver.find_elements(by, locator)
    displayed_elements = [element for element in elements if element.is_displayed()]
    return len(displayed_elements) > 0
```

Comment: This worked like an absolute charm! Thank you so much!